# Irreducible aperiodic Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $\Omega$ be a finite state space, and let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a Markov chain on $\Omega$. Suppose $(X_n)$ is irreducible, i.e.  $\forall \omega,\omega'\in\Omega$ $\exists N\geq 1$ $P(X_N=\omega'|X_1=\omega)>0$.

I would like to prove that $(X_n)$ is aperiodic if and only if:
$\exists N\geq 1$ $\forall \omega,\omega'\in\Omega$ $P(X_N=\omega'|X_1=\omega)>0$. $(P)$

[$(P)\Rightarrow$ aperiodic] seems clear, indeed let $\omega\in \Omega$ :
$(P)$ implies that there exists $N\geq1$ such that $P(X_N=\omega|X_1=\omega)>0$, but also $P(X_{N+1}=\omega|X_1=\omega)>0$. We conclude since $PGCD(N,N+1)=1$.

I cannot manage to prove the converse.

Comment: Your use of $\Omega$ for the state space and $\omega$ for its elements is extremely confusing since those generally denote the underlying probability space on which the random variables are defined, e.g. $X_n:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is the map $\omega\mapsto X_n(\omega)$.

Comment: As for your question, it has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242087/how-to-prove-irreducible-and-aperiodic-markov-chain-is-regular